# Python 3 Rock Paper Scissors ... AGAIN

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure what I did, but now when I play the game it ends after I input my choice( r, p or s)
Is it something to do with the validation?

Here is code:

```
    from random import randint

    computer = randint(1,3)

    r = "r"
    p = "p"
    s = "s"
    print ("The computer has chosen. Your turn")
    player = input ("r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")

    a = 1
    while (a == 1):
            if (player not in(r,p,s)): 
                    player = input ("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
                    if (player in (r,p,s)):
                            a = 2

    if (computer == 1):
            AI = ("rock")

    if (computer == 2):
            AI = ("paper")

    if (computer == 3):
            AI = ("scissors")

    if (player == r and computer == 1):
            print ("lol draw")


    if (player == p and computer == 2):
            print ("lol draw")


    if (player == s and computer == 3):
            print ("lol draw")


    if (player == r and computer == 3):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == p and computer == 1):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == s and computer == 2):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == s and computer == 1):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == r and computer == 2):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == p and computer == 3):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)
```

Comment: As a side note, instead of using `computer = randint(1, 3)` and then a chain of `if` statements to test it and set `AI` accordingly, just use `random.choice`: `AI = choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enter an infinite loop if you enter either r, p or s.

```
a = 1
while (a == 1): #always enters
        if (player not in(r,p,s)): #if it is r or p or s it skips this
                player = input ("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
                if (player in (r,p,s)):
                        a = 2
        #and loops back, a being still 1
```

You are looking for something like this:

```
player = None
while player not in (r, p, s):
    player = input ("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
```

Comment: @Because you never enter this `if`-suite.

Comment: Thank you, works now. 1 less thing to learn about python now :)

Comment: will tick when I can, also, can that "player = none" be "player = "anything I want to put in here""?

Comment: It can be any value, except r, p or s.

Comment: Right, I are 4eva in ure debt

Comment: actually, this only works if you take away the player = NONE

Comment: If you have define `player` somewhere earlier in your code, sure.

Comment: @carpetguy: If you don't want to define `player` to a sentinel value, you will have to restructure this as a `while True:` with an `if` and a `break`, so you don't try to check `player` before you've set it. Either way works, but you have to do one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that can be done to clean up this code, but your problem comes from this:

```
while (a == 1):
        if (player not in(r,p,s)): 
                player = input ("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
                if (player in (r,p,s)): #this shouldn't be indented this far
                        a = 2           #this one either, obviously :)
```

Comment: OH, OK thanks never realised

Comment: would tick this if you could do 2

Comment: As a suggestion, rather than explicitly listing out every combination (which would be painful if you played rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock), use a game matrix. Rock-paper-scissors (in this order) would have a matrix of [[0, -1, 1], [1, 0, -1], [-1, 1, 0]]. 1 designates a win, 0 designates a draw, and -1 designates a loss. In this matrix, the indices of rock, paper, and scissors are 0, 1, and 2 respectively. To determine if rock beats paper, do game_matrix[0][2], or using a namedtuple, game_matrix['rock']['scissors'] or `def versus(you, opponent): return game_matrix[you][opponent]`

Answer (score 1):

Right now your program is stuck in an infinite loop from lines 12-16. You should probably work out why yourself because you will learn more from it.

On a note of style, you use excessive if statements which make the program hard to read. Try figuring out a more concise method to answer the question without enumerating each case.

Comment: thanks, good answer. But if you read the above answers you'll know that you are just reiterating them

Comment: Guess they beat me to it. They weren't there when I typed this in